# Brand new razor projects return 404 on debug VS

Tags: debugging, razor, http-status-code-404

I have tried multiple times to create new razor projects from the visual studio 2022 and 2019

the boiler plate template is as follows, however when I click the debug button , the console outputs that its listening as normal as per below

```
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: https://localhost:7277
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: http://localhost:5227
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
```

however when I navigate to either of those urls I get a 404.

However, if I dot a dotnet run or dotnet watch through the console, runs fine with no 404 errors.

Here is my lunchSettings.json file (untouched from the boilerplate)

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:25708",
      "sslPort": 44374
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5227",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7277;http://localhost:5227",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

and folder structure (all unchanged from the vs boilerplate)

[image]

and here is the debug bin

[image]

i tried resetting vs settings and starting mutliple projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I managed to fix this but only by completely uninstalling visual studio and re-installing it.